# Heroku fails to install av (pyav)

Tags: python, heroku, pyav

I have been trying to set up my Python web app that uses opencv, tensorflow and av modules but keeps failing. I have tried using the `Aptfile` to install several Ubuntu libraries (`libsm6, libxrender1`, etc.) and the install still fails.

After failing the install, the heroku server resolves to building the av module from source which fails as well, with gcc failing here:

```
src/av/codec/codec.c:4003:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘av_codec_iterate’; did you mean ‘av_codec_next’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    __pyx_v_ptr = av_codec_iterate((&__pyx_v_opaque));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                av_codec_next
src/av/codec/codec.c:4003:17: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    __pyx_v_ptr = av_codec_iterate((&__pyx_v_opaque));
                ^
src/av/codec/codec.c: In function ‘__pyx_pymod_exec_codec’:
src/av/codec/codec.c:6117:36: error: ‘AV_CODEC_CAP_HARDWARE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘AV_CODEC_CAP_DR1’?
__pyx_t_7 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_int(AV_CODEC_CAP_HARDWARE); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(0, 121, __pyx_L1_error)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    AV_CODEC_CAP_DR1
src/av/codec/codec.c:6117:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/av/codec/codec.c:6138:36: error: ‘AV_CODEC_CAP_HYBRID’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘AV_CODEC_CAP_DR1’?
__pyx_t_7 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_int(AV_CODEC_CAP_HYBRID); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(0, 125, __pyx_L1_error)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    AV_CODEC_CAP_DR1
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Has anyone experienced this? Or any experience with using av/pyav in Heroku? Please tell me anything that I missed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Heroku works better using `requirements.txt` than `Pipfile`. After changing the install file, the deployment process went fine.